# change mysql datetime to php datetime-local not working by strtotime()

Tags: php, html, mysql, datetime, html-table

I have mysql table with datatime type and i want it to show in php/html table

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$time1 = strtotime($row["Request Date"]);
$myFormatForView = date("d/m/y g:i A", $time1);
```

output

```
11/02/15 10:18 AM
```

now i tried this code to work with html table

```
<td>  <input type='datetime-local' id='txt_dateid_".$i."' value=".$myFormatForView."  disabled></td>
```

but i am not getting any output

full code

```
 <?php
        include_once "connector.php";

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tablename";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

        $i=0;
        $row=0;
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $time1 = strtotime($row["Request Date"]);
                                    $myFormatForView = date("d/m/y g:i A", $time1);
                                echo ($myFormatForView);
               echo
                 "
                <tr>
                 <td size='20' align='center'>  <input type='text' id='txt_orderid_".$i."'value=" . $row["Order ID"]. " disabled> </td>                      
                 <td>  <button type='button' id='btn_update_".$i."'  onclick='myFunction($i)'>update</button> </td>
                 <td>  <button type='button' id='btn_delete_".$i."'  onclick='DeleteFunction($i)'>delete</button> </td>
                 <td>  <input type='datetime-local'  id='txt_dateid_".$i."'value="  . $myFormatForView. " disabled></td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_timeid_".$i."'class='txt_id_".$i."'     value="  . $row["Fixed Time"]. " disabled></td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_toolid_".$i."'     class='txt_id_".$i."'   value="  . $row["Tool"]. " disabled> </td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_nameid_".$i."'         class='txt_id_".$i."'    value="  . $row["Name"]. " disabled> </td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_emailid_".$i."'        class='txt_id_".$i."'    value="  . $row["Email"]. " disabled> </td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_countid_".$i."'    class='txt_id_".$i."'    value="  . $row["Country Entered"]. " disabled> </td>


      </tr>

                 ";
                $i++;
            }
```

edit 1 :

this code also does not work

```
<td> <input type='datetime-local' id='txt_dateid_".$i."' 'value'=".$myFormatForView." disabled></td>
```

[image: see the request date colmn i want to fill it up]

Edit 2:

Comment: try this,  echo "<td>  <input type='datetime-local' id='txt_dateid_".$i." 'value=".$myFormatForView."  disabled></td>";

Comment: @bhaveshvala it does not work

Comment: @Hudixt the code you posted in ans. does not work.

Comment: looks like messed up quotes to me.. why not use echo?

Comment: @pjp  quotes are working very well, don't worry about that. Question is 'datetime' and 'datetime-local' integration ia not working.

Answer (score 0):

Error Spotted you haven't put quotes in value `''`. Use this

```
<td>  <input type='datetime-local' id='txt_dateid_".$i."' value='".$myFormatForView."'  disabled></td>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You have there missing spaces between attributes (`id` and `value`) and missing quotes around the `value` attribute:

```
<td>  
    <input type='datetime-local' id='txt_dateid_" . $i . "' value='" . $myFormatForView . "' disabled>
</td>
```

Note: for better reading I've indented `input` in `td` and put there optinal spaces around dots `.`.

Comment: What does it mean? I see you have there ´type=datetime-local´, it should be ´name´. No other probléms should be there.

Comment: how would 'name' work let me post an image i'll show you what I am trying to do, ok.

Answer (score 0):

you have mistaken  here

```
<td>  <input type='datetime-local' id='txt_dateid_".$i." 'value=".$myFormatForView."  disabled></td>
```

replace this line with below one

```
<td>  <input type='datetime-local' id='txt_dateid_".$i."' 'value='".$myFormatForView."'  disabled></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the quotes for value attribute. Try this:

```
<td>  <input type='datetime-local' id='txt_dateid_".$i."' value='".$myFormatForView."'  disabled></td>
```