# how to select default value drop down menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I want to dynamically select the default value on the drop down menu
the value are stored on mysql server which is retrieved by `$row['order status']`
and it has only 4 values stored in the server `Open Pending Closed Success`

so i have choose the default value from these 4 value

```
$selected are all initialised to false or '0' or disabled
```

i am trying the following code but it is not working

```
 if($row["Order Status"]=="Open"){ 
       $selected='selected';
    }
    if($row["Order Status"]=="Pending"){
       $selected1='selected';
    }
    if($row["Order Status"]=="Closed"){
       $selected2='selected';
    }
    if($row["Order Status"]=="Success"){
       $selected3='selected';
    }   
    echo"
    <select id='txt_orderstatusid_'  class='txt_id_' >
       <option ".$selected." value='Open'>Open </option>
       <option ".$selected1." value='Pending'>Pending </option>
       <option ".$selected2."value='Closed'>Closed </option>
       <option ".$selected3."value='Success'>Success </option>
    </select>"
```

i have tried this also

```
echo "<select   id='txt_orderstatusid_'  class='txt_id_' >
<option selected=".$selected." value='Open'>Open </option>
<option selected=".$selected1." value='Pending'>Pending </option>
<option selected=".$selected2."value='Closed'>Closed </option>
<option selected=".$selected3."value='Success'>Success </option>
</select>   "
```

it also does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check db values at option directly Try

```
<select id='txt_orderstatusid_'  class='txt_id_' >
    <option <?php if(isset($row["Order Status"]) && $row["Order Status"]=="Open") echo 'selected="selected"';?> value='Open'>Open </option>
    <option <?php if(isset($row["Order Status"]) && $row["Order Status"]=="Pending") echo 'selected="selected"';?> value='Pending'>Pending </option>
    <option <?php if(isset($row["Order Status"]) && $row["Order Status"]=="Closed") echo 'selected="selected"';?> value='Closed'>Closed </option>
    <option <?php if(isset($row["Order Status"]) && $row["Order Status"]=="Success") echo 'selected="selected"';?> value='Success'>Success </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: could you exlain the code what you did here i am not able to understand.

Comment: just matching db values with option values and adding selected

Comment: it does not work.because my entire code is inside echo.

Comment: just remove echo and close php tag and after this code open php tag

Comment: its not that simple my original code of at least 350 lines and it would req. a lot of changes. but thanks for your help. i am trying to manipulate the code to run let see.

Comment: thank you for your help. if you have time I have another question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406553/change-mysql-datetime-to-php-datetime-local-not-working-by-strtotime/28406661#28406661)

Comment: @RakeshSharma, I am getting the same issue but my select is already in single quote like $dropdown='<select><option></option>.  </select>'; then how can we use if condition inside option?